# Modify Textext Suggestion

Tags: jquery

I am using TextExt: http://textextjs.com/

This is my code currently:

```
$('#company').textext({
    plugins : 'autocomplete filter ajax',

    autocomplete : {
        render : function (suggestion) {
            var organization = suggestion.split('#');

            return '<strong>' + organization[0] + '</strong><br />' + organization[1];
        }                            
    },

    ajax : {
        url : '/organizations.json',
        dataType : 'json',
        cacheResults : true
    }
});
```

This is what is output by the json:

> > ["Organization#Address"]

It currently works fine, but when a user clicks on a suggestion, the textbox contains "Organization#Address". My question is, how do I modify textext, so that when a user clicks on a suggestion, it only fills "Organization" into the textbox, rather than the whole json suggestion.

If this is unclear, I can explain further.

Thanks

Comment: I did not get a good grasp on your question.All your suggestions are always appended by "#Address"? or only this one? what i meant is can't you strip the last characters if they are same all the time

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still wanted an answer (given the question was asked nine months ago), but just in case here is my suggestion based on some code that I wrote in a similar situation:

```
$('#company').textext({
    plugins : 'autocomplete filter ajax',

    autocomplete : ...as before

    ajax : ... as before

    // new bit
    ext: {
         selectFromDropdown: function() {
             var self = this;
             var suggestion = self.selectedSuggestionElement().data('text-suggestion');
             var organization

             if (suggestion) {
                 organization = suggestion.split('#');

                 self.val( self.itemManager().itemToString(organization[0]));
                 self.core().getFormData();
             }

             self.trigger('hideDropdown');
         }
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this specific version of the code, so it may need a little tweak.

Another alternative may be to write your own ItemManager.